# Why am I not able to switch between two Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have tried everything but still, I am not able to change Fragments from CalculatorP1 to Calculator_P2. When I click the button only one Fragment is shown but when I click the button again the second Fragment does not show itself in the APP. I tried everything and I also tried to use TWO BUTTONS bt only one Fragment Shows itself. The second Fragment doesn't show itself. If I switch the fragments only the first Fragment shows bt the 2nd fragment doesn't show itself. 
Please help.

[My App... See how the button text changes but the Fragment remains the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqZEa.png)

My XML codes are given Below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="98dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bn_f1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bn_f2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 2" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="276dp"
    android:layout_height="350sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
```

My Activity.java is given below:

```
package com.example.sudeepsarker.sudeepcalculatorvv;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private Button bn_fragment;
private boolean status= false;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bn_fragment = findViewById(R.id.bn_f1);

    bn_fragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            if(!status){

               CalculatorP1 p1 = new CalculatorP1();
               fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,p1);
               fragmentTransaction.commit();
               bn_fragment.setText("Fragment 2");
               status=true;
            }
            else{

                Calculator_P2 p2= new Calculator_P2();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,p2);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                bn_fragment.setText("Fragment 1");
                status=false;
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

My Fragment one xml file:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="350sp"
tools:context=".CalculatorP1"
android:background="#8F3A1E"
>

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My first Part of calculator"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    />
```

My Fragment Two XML File:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="350sp"
tools:context=".CalculatorP1"
android:background="#077715"
>

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Second Part of calculator"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    />
```

Comment: Hi. Am on mobile, so I'm not able to test code, but have you tried fragmentTransaction.replace instead of fragmentTransaction.add?

Comment: oh! it works Now. Thanks... I thought i should use fragmentTransaction.replace for other occations. Bt i was wrong. Thanx a lot... @GarrenFitzenreiter

Comment: Replace is perfectly fine for this occasion. I believe .add was loading  the fragment into the container, but your initial fragment was in front of it and blocking it from view. And you're welcome. Good luck!

Comment: @GarrenFitzenreiter iT works only in my NOX player bt when i intall it in my XIOAMI MI A1 and press the button the App crashes.

Comment: Check your logcat after it crashes and see what it says

Comment: the code:
bn_fragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
if(!status){
CalculatorP1 p1 = new CalculatorP1();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,p1);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
bn_fragment.setText("Fragment 2");
status=true;}

Comment: else{
Calculator_P2 p2= new Calculator_P2();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,p2);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
bn_fragment.setText("Fragment 1");
status=false;}}});

Comment: Look for the error where it tell you what went wrong. Should be an error message and a blue link telling you what script and which line it occurred on. Clicking on it should bring you right to the problem

Comment: Process: com.example.sudeepsarker.sudeepcalculatorvv, PID: 17120
    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.sudeepsarker.sudeepcalculatorvv.MainActivity@b415998 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
        at com.example.sudeepsarker.sudeepcalculatorvv.CalculatorP1.onAttach(CalculatorP1.java:83)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1223)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2407)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2186)

Comment: at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2142)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2043)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:719)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)